# Blue Ocean missing branch/commit info

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Pipeline job that has a parameter for the BRANCH_NAME to specify which branch to build from my bitbucket repo.  I use this in the Branch Specifier as ${BRANCH_NAME} in the pipeline definition (Pipeline script from SCM).

The builds run fine, except that in the Blue Ocean UI it doesn't list the branch or commit info. Any way I can get this to appear?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the information of **Branch** and **Commit** in the pipeline job of Blue Ocean UI, you will need the [Pipeline: Multibranch](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch) plugin. Using the Multibranch pipeline plugin will create jobs for each branch in that repository that contains a jenkinsfile. When it does that it will get the information from which branch it is coming, and show it in the Blue Ocean UI. And if there is a commit related to that build, it will show the commit hash.

For more information on the Pipeline: Multibranch plugin, check out the following [link](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/).

This is how I was able to get and show the Branch/Commit information in Blue Ocean UI.

Comment: While I know this is correct, I can't help but think it should be possible to get those fields to populate with a single pipeline.